# Tried everything - can't get composer.json on BitBucket to require a package (the Rackspace API library)

Tags: git, github, composer-php, bitbucket, rackspace

I have a simple repository on BitBucket. In that repository I have this composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "MyPackage/MyBundle",
    "require": {
        "rackspace/php-opencloud": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud"
        }
    ]
}
```

When doing a composer update I get this error:

```
- Installation request for mypackage/mybundle dev-master -> satisfiable by MyPackage/MyBundle[dev-master].
- MyPackage/MyBundle dev-master requires rackspace/php-opencloud dev-master -> no matching package found.
```

I have tried various variations of the GitHub URL, although as it's also available on Packagist I didn't think I would need it. I also tried type:"vcs" but I get exactly the same error.

If I remove the Rackspace dependency then everything else installs fine. It is definitely something to do with the way I am requiring Rackspace.

How do I get this to install? Is it anything to do with the fact my repository is on BitBucket and I'm trying to get one from GitHub?

Comment: I just tried this and it worked as expected. What version of composer are you using?

Comment: It was an older version but I just did a composer self-update and I get the same problem. Are you using BitBucket?

Comment: "minimum-stability": "dev" ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to need a more specific package version. This is how it's done:

```
{
    "name": "MyPackage/MyBundle",
    "require": {
        "rackspace/php-opencloud": "1.10.*"
    }
}
```